# Displaying a number in Indian format using angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, vuejs2, angular-pipe

I want to print numbers with commas as `thousands`, `lacs`, `crores` separators. for e.g:

```
     10,000 - ten thousand
   1,00,000 - 1 lakh
  10,00,000 - 10 lakh
1,00,00,000 - 1 crore
```

I have used angular's number pipe to implement comma separated values but not getting proper output it displays like this `1,000,000 - 10 lakh`.

How can i implement above functionality using angular/javascript or is there any pipe for this in angular?

Comment: why vuejs is in the tags ? and so do jquery ?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [.toLocalString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

> The toLocaleString() method returns a string with a language-sensitive
>   representation of this number.

```js
var tenK= 10000;
var oneL = 100000;
var tenL = 1000000;
var oneCr = 10000000;
console.log(tenK.toLocaleString('en-IN'));
console.log(oneL.toLocaleString('en-IN'));
console.log(tenL.toLocaleString('en-IN'));
console.log(oneCr.toLocaleString('en-IN'));
```

Answer (score 6):

> You can do it with [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

In `localeString` you need to provide locales in this case you need to use ***`en-IN`***

```js
let num1 = 1000;
let num2 = 10000;
let num3 = 1000000;

console.log(num1.toLocaleString('en-IN'));
console.log(num2.toLocaleString('en-IN'));
console.log(num3.toLocaleString('en-IN'));
```

Comment: how this is going to fulfill his requirement, while he already mentioned that I don't need in standard formate, he wants to formate currency in his custom formate.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you have used pipe in correct way,

but just to confirm we can use currency pipe like

```
 {{price|currency:'INR':true}}
```

here is a skeleton syntax for currency by angular

```
{{ value_expression | currency [ : currencyCode [ : display [ : digitsInfo [ : locale ] ] ] ] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with regular expressions like this in Javascript:

```js
formatNumber = (num)=>{
    return num.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
var formattedNumber = formatNumber(10000000);
console.log(formattedNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation to achieve this

Create an custom pipe:

```
import {Inject, Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'currencyFormat'
})
export class CurrencyFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor() {
  }

  transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {
    if (value === undefined || value === null) {
      return '';
    }
    return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { style: 'currency', currency: 'INR' }).format(value);
  }

}
```

use this pipe in you template to get output in Indian format.

Please checkout Intl.NumberFormat documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) to understand the parameters.